# Как сделать выборку из ряда элементов, где нет определённого значения?

Tags: sql, plsql, выборка

Прошу помочь с выборкой sql.

Задача примерно следующая:
Есть таблица:

```
ID   | START_DATE|  END_DATE
----------------------------------
10   | 01.01.2005|  02.12.2007    
10   | 03.12.2007|  01.02.2014    
10   | 02.02.2014|  31.12.2015    
10   | 01.01.2016|  05.05.2017    
10   | 06.05.2017|     NULL
20   | 01.11.2004|  15.11.2004    
20   | 16.11.2004|  06.09.2013    
20   | 07.09.2013|  03.02.2015
```

Нужно вывести только те ID, для которых нет нулловских значений в END_DATE. То есть, "END_DATE is not null" В данном случае это будет ID = 20. Но как конкретно это реализовать, не могу понять.
Самое первое, что приходит в голову - это написать что-то вроде такого запроса:

```
select t.id from table t
where 1=1
and not exists (select 1 from table t where end_date is null)
```

но он, естественно не работает, как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

не знаток plsql, но, например, так?

```
SELECT distinct id  FROM t
MINUS
SELECT distinct id  FROM t WHERE end_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Здесь то же самое, о чём я отписал в ответе ниже. Запрос рабочий, но в моём случае не сработает как надо, т.к. будет выполняться слишком долго из-за огромного числа записей в таблице.

Comment: @Lotrein При наличии индекса `(id, end_date)` должно выполняться достаточно шустро.

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(end_date) = COUNT(id)
```

PS. Надеюсь, в таблице нет записи, где и `id`, и `end_date` содержат NULL? а то и она выведется...

Comment: Запрос понятен, и сработал бы, но к сожалению, в моём случае в таблице миллионы записей и выполняться запрос будет слишком долго.
Ну и неудивительно, ведь он каждое значение с каждым будет сравнивать(

Comment: @Lotrein *он каждое значение с каждым будет сравнивать* ??? вот этой фразы не понял - ну то есть совсем. *в таблице миллионы записей* Добавьте в текст вопроса сведения о: количестве записей в таблице, количестве различных значений `id` в таблице, ожидаемое количество записей в запросе. Хотя бы приблизительно. И обязательно структуру таблицы, включая индексы.